# Could not click on anchor href element using Selenium Java webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, anchor

Below is the html code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
STK10000251
VESUVIUS29
Vesuvius India Ltd  
</a>
```

And I have written the following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'STK10000251')]")).click();
```

After executing the above statement I'm getting below error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element
> reference: element is not attached to the page document

Where am I getting it wrong

Comment: `StaleElementReferenceException` comes when the element is not attached with page.did you use explicit wait to click?

Comment: @KunduK no I did not...

Comment: wow it worked!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `elementToBeClickable`()

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'STK10000251')]")));
element.click();
```

Comment: Could you please provide explanation for this, how is StaleElementReferenceException linked with the wait.

Comment: @Sree: Due to slowness of the application when webdriver try to interact with element it not attached with the page and it becomes stale sometimes.However I would have expect `no such element` error instead `StaleElementReferenceException`